# How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to login to Facebook. After a successful login, I get a browser popup:

[image: Show Notifications]

How with the webdriver can I click Allow and proceed forward?

Comment: make it manually allow ones

Comment: right now i am doing the same! but is there no way to make selenium do it?

Comment: Same here, but I'm using Codeception (php). Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't necessarily need to "Allow", but just want to get rid of the dialog, you can also just simulate the escape key, which will dismiss the dialog. `new Actions().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();`

Comment: `browser.keys("Escape"); // Dismiss "notifications" dialog box.`

Matthijs, that works!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Please Follow below steps :

**A) USING JAVA :**

> **For Old Chrome Version (<50):**

```java
//Create a instance of ChromeOptions class
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

//Add chrome switch to disable notification - "**--disable-notifications**"
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        
//Set path for driver exe 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path/to/driver/exe");

//Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor
WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

> **For New Chrome Version (>50):**

```java
//Create a map to store  preferences 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
//add key and value to map as follow to switch off browser notification
//Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
    
//Create an instance of ChromeOptions 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
// set ExperimentalOption - prefs 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    
//Now Pass ChromeOptions instance to ChromeDriver Constructor to initialize chrome driver which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

---

> **For Firefox :**

```java
WebDriver driver ;
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

---

**B) USING PYTHON :**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1}
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=option, executable_path="path-of-driver\chromedriver.exe"
)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
```

**C) USING C#:**

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications"); // to disable notification
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: this works for older versions of chromedriver.  (Chrome 49 compatible ones...)  This does not work for later versions.  Not sure when the cutoff was, but for the latest version you need to use the prefs HashMap option. Saurabh Gaur's answer.

Comment: the question is about how to ALLOW by default, the `profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications=2` will DISALLOW by default, to ALLOW it should be `profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications=1`

Comment: How to do this for safari?

Comment: This is so neat that you have provided the 3 common most languages used for selenium.

Answer (score 15):

```py
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time


class SendMsgSkype(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.get("https://web.skype.com/ru/")
```

It works for me.
More details here: http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@t@a@TardyParty-HEAD@oxbiz.py/21/selenium.webdriver.Chrome

Comment: This works for me, using Python 3.7 and latest selenium in Feb 2019. For the noobish like me, and also if you are using selenium to scrape some results after login (consensus seems use requests package unless you need login / click buttons), rather than testing webpages, key lines are: `from selenium import webdriver....options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/to/ChromeDriver.exe", options= options)` or as OP wanted in fact to enable notifications, presumably `("--enable-notifications")` is the main alternative.

Answer (score 12):

This not an alert box, so you can't handle it using `Alert`, this is a chrome browser notification, To Switch off this browser notification you need to create chrome preference map with chrome option as below :

```java
//Create prefs map to store all preferences 
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
//Put this into prefs map to switch off browser notification
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);

//Create chrome options to set this prefs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    
//Now initialize chrome driver with chrome options which will switch off this browser notification on the chrome browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

//Now do your further steps
```

Hope it helps..:)

Answer (score 8):

The one and only working solution I've come across so far is this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: doesn't work, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440682/cant-accept-popup?noredirect=1#comment89851546_51440682

Answer (score 2):

no answer has been accepted yet, this following code works for me

ruby, rspec, capybara

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications" => 2,}
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_options: { prefs: prefs })

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {

   // Check the presence of alert
   Alert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();

   // if present consume the alert
   alert.Accept();

  } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
     //code to do if not exist.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook authentication window displays an overlay that covers the **continue as [username]** button.

[image]

This makes the continue button un-clickable. To circumvent that problem, you can hide those layers programmatically using JavaScript (not recommended) using this code (don't do this).

```
  // DO NOT USE THIS CODE.
  function forceClickSetup(targetSelector) {
      return browser.selectorExecute("div", 
      function(divs, targetSelector) {
        var button = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          if(!divs[i].contains(button)) {
            divs[i].remove();
          }
        }
        return i;
    }, targetSelector);
  }
```

Or instead, you can dismiss the notifications dialog, after which facebook will uncover the **continue** button. But before wildly hitting `Escape` at the browser, first make sure that the **continue** button has been shown.

```
// USE THIS CODE.
browser.waitForVisible("[name=__CONFIRM__]");
browser.keys("Escape"); // Dismiss "notifications" dialog box.

var confirmButtonSelector = "[name=__CONFIRM__]";
```

This solution is really Matthijs' (see comments above)

Comment: What is `browser` in this instance?

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I needed .It's Chrome if anyone like @Roymunson wants to know

Answer (score 0):

if you play with Ruby and Capybara try this code

```
    Capybara.register_driver :chrome_no_image_popup_maximize do |app|
    # 2: disable, other than 2 means enable it
    preferences = {
        "profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications" => 2,
        "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" => 2,
        "profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups" => 2   
    }

    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome( 
        'chromeOptions' => {
            'prefs' => preferences, 
        } 
    )

    args = [ "--start-maximized" ]

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :args => args})
end

Capybara.default_driver = :chrome_no_image_popup_maximize
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome_no_image_popup_maximize
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using selenium - 4 you can apply these changes to handle such issues. It worked perfectly for me.

```
    public WebDriver openBrowser() {
    if (driver == null) {
        String browserType = myProp.getProperty("browser");
        System.out.println(browserType);

        if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            // Create ChromeOptions
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
            options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

            // Add geolocation permission
            options.addArguments("--enable-geolocation");

            // Initialize Chrome driver with options
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        } else if (browserType.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            // Create Firefox profile
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("geo.enabled", true);
            profile.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", true);
            profile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", true);
            profile.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", true);

            // Initialize FirefoxOptions
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.setProfile(profile);

            // Initialize Firefox driver with options
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        }
    }
    return driver;
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).