# How to handle any element in webdriver when we run browser its asked to allow or not allow

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to handle [image: THIS] type of notification in selenium web driver.

Comment: show us first what you tried so far ?

Comment: @Sunil Kumawat try this approach to handle this popup : https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

Comment: Please provide some info, what You've tried, and what is the problem.

Comment: i was just trying to open facebook login page, then entering email id and password.then click on login button . after it i want to click on profile but when ever i tried this above mention pop up coming

Comment: got the solution

Comment: ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: above mention code disabling that notification

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to handle an alert window on a webpage while running.

Below code can help you out:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

You can also decline the alert box:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert().dismiss();
```

Some useful links:
[Alert](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts)
[Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)