# Cant allow notification which may not be an alert

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.5

As suggested by @DebanjanB the popup which is clearly visible between the `WebDriverWait starts` and  `WebDriverWait ends` message may not be an alert. How do we press allow in such case.

[image]

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = { "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2 }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(url)
try:
    print("WebDriverWait starts")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present(), 'Timed out waiting for PA creation confirmation popup to appear.')
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("WebDriverWait ends: ", e)
    pass
```

> WebDriverWait starts
>
> WebDriverWait ends:  Message: Timed out waiting for PA creation confirmation popup to appear.

Comment: What exception did you get? Doubt if that's an alert.

Comment: Message: Timed out waiting for PA creation confirmation popup to appear.

Comment: @eduPeeth I also suspect so, previously it used to work, now it isn't working as the look and feel of this alert changed slightly.

Comment: But it's an alert because disabling works..`chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
`

Comment: @ishandutta2007 What you are seeing in the AUT, historically is not an alert but a notification. Perhaps Andersson as well have pointed you to the right direction. If you feel your question is not a duplicate please edit your question to make it indifferent from the existing dup marked discussion.

Comment: @DebanjanB this selenium code is very old and used to work fine till now, now it isn't working as the look and feel of this alert changed slightly