# Cannot accept alert in Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

When I open a page, an alert is being displayed. I tried to accept it using the below code.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.ultimateqa.com/fake-landing-page/");
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

It's not working and got NoAlertPresentException. Then I tried to wait for the alert with the below code.

```
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    alert.accept();
```

It is still not working and got timeoutException now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have visit the website you provided in the example and have noticed that there is an 'notification' popup not an alert.

Here you can find more information how to handle it:

> [How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Don't submit link to another SO ticket as your own answer. Just vote to close question as duplicate instead

Comment: Thanks for the link. It solved my problem.

Comment: How can I identify the difference between an alert and a notification?

Comment: As I've to use alert().accept() for an alert and follow the procedure mentioned in the above-mentioned link for a notification.