# How to handle allow pop up on the chrome browser by Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

How to handle allow pop up on the chrome browser by Selenium Java

I'm using

```
chrome=69.0.3497.100
Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161
Selenium-jave: 3.14.0
```

Note: I have tried every possible solution from: [How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

and and more

Comment: ......Why are you trying to do this. This is a user interaction that require client side consent. Why are you trying to by pass this. I can only think of nefarious reasons. Also forcing the allow or taking away user consent for sensitive data is very very illegal.

Comment: Really appreciated your security concern, but it's required for testing!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following capability:

- avoids the need to grant camera/microphone permissions.

> --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream