# How do I allow chrome popups on Python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to allow the popup of the chrome in the below screenshot.

[image]

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
...

time.sleep(10)

Alert(driver).accept()
```

Comment: You may find something interesting here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39997484/7652544

Comment: Well, that's chrome pop up not web application pop up.

Comment: @SebastienD
Thanks! It did not work in secret mode, but it's ok.