# How to disable alert in website automation testing by Java?

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
prefs = {
      "safebrowsing.enabled": "false",
      "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2,
      "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0}
```

Above code is in Python.I have searched for the answer/code-sample like this in Java Automation Testing but I could not find out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click Allow on Show Notifications popup using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Please see the comment.