# Python3 and Selenium - Manage permission popup

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I need from my Python script to just be able to Block this permission request.

[image: Popup window]

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

bot = webdriver.Chrome()
time.sleep(2)
bot.get("https://MYWEBSITE")
```

I tried `bot.switch_to.alert`, but it crashed with:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
```

I found solutions using tabs and enter, but here this does not work. 
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver) wasn't functional either. Any suggestions? Thanks.